# How can I recover from failed app update?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

Twice now I have apps fail to install during an update and then been unable to restart the process or use the app. I am using the Update All function in the "Apps" App.

Last time it effected only one app. Despite full reboots and going back into the Update screen the failed app was stuck at the "Installing" step. I could not resume the update or use the app. I finally deleted the app and reinstalled and things seem to go fine.

This time it failed installing the Twitter app and the two apps after it in the list now are also stuck. Again I've tried full shutdown and reboot with no luck. I can update other apps but those three seem stuck in limbo. I suppose I can delete them are reinstall as before but is there a better way?

Comment: What happens if you tap the app on your device? If the installation is *paused*, this should resume it. This procedure needs to be repeated for each app.

Comment: The app is just locked with the installing bar. I've deleted the apps and reinstalled but now had this happen a couple of times.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of iOS? If not, I'd recommend updating. If you are, I'd try doing a clean installation, as in, reinstalling iOS, and not restoring from a backup.

Comment: Yes this is on iOS 6. In fact it only really started since I upgraded.

Comment: Then I would definitely start by reinstalling the update, and if that doesn't fix the issue, then I would do a reset without restoring from backup.

Comment: It's an annoyance that has happened occasionally. I am not going to go through the hassle of trying to reinstall iOS6 (not sure where to even start with that). Was just looking to see if there was a way to restart an app update without deleting and reinstalling it. I will just wait and see if a future update to iOS6 fixes this issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has now happened a couple of more times. I've been able to resolve this the last couple of times by tapping the app back on the main screen (ie not in the app store). The label below it changes to 'Waiting'. Then tapping it again it changes the label to 'Loading' or 'Installing' and the update finally completes. I can then update other apps.

Otherwise the only other solution is to delete and reinstall the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try transferring the apps to your iTunes library (if they are not already there) with the "Send purchases" function. Then sync your iTunes library with your iDevice.

This could clear the issue.

Comment: I haven't plugged my iPad into my computer in months. I could maybe try this next time it happens but really trying to operate without using iTunes.